# How can I clone over https in bitbucket?

Tags: git, https, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

There is a recent announcement from Atlassian,

**Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication.**

How can I clone a repository over HTTPS in bitbucket?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bbitbucket%5d%20application%20password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Git Authentication, you can try to use an app password.

Here is the link for more details - https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/